# Task with feedback dialog helper class

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I'm currently working in a `Windows.Forms` project where its very common that I need to show a responsive feedback form while a task runs. These tasks take typically around 5 to 10 seconds to complete and the user can't do anything else until the task has successfully finished or failed.

To keep the UI responsive I've cooked up a little helper class. I'm pretty new to tasks and the async programming environment so I am not sure if I'm overkilling things here or going off in a completely wrong direction:

This is the small helper class:

```
internal sealed class TaskManagerWithFeedbackDialog<TController> where TController : IViewController, new() 
{
    public static Task<TReturn> RunTask<TReturn>(Func<TReturn> func)
    {
        if (func == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("func");
        }

        var manager = new _AsyncTaskManager<TReturn>(func);

        using (var view = new TController())
        {
            var task = manager.Start(view);
            view.ShowViewDialog();
            return task;
        }
    }

    private class _AsyncTaskManager<T>
    {
        private readonly Func<T> taskFunc;

        public _AsyncTaskManager(Func<T> func)
        {
            taskFunc = func;
        }

        public Task<T> Start(IViewController feedBackView)
        {
            var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(taskFunc);

            task.ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                feedBackView.CloseView();
            }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);

            task.ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                feedBackView.CloseView();
                return t.Result;
            }, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted);

            return task;
        }
    }
}
```

Where the implementation of `IViewController.CloseView()` would look like this:

```
public virtual void CloseView()
{
    if (View.InvokeRequired)
    {
        View.Invoke(new Action(View.Close));
    }
    else
    {
        View.Close();
    }
}
```

Another issue I am not sure about is where is the best place to handle `ArregateException`?. Right now I don't handle anything as I don't need to clean up anything if a task fails. I simply check the returned task for any errors. Is this the right thing to do? Do async tasks always fail 'silently'? If I needed to clean up, where would it be? Inside `.ContinueWith( .... , TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted)`?

Answer (score 2):

Few minor things:

- If `TaskManagerWithFeedbackDialog` is not a nested class then `internal` is redundant and can be dropped.
- `TaskManagerWithFeedbackDialog` has - so far - just one single `static` method. Until you will add more methods make it a `static class`. No need to create any instance.
- <del>`TController` instance is disposed just after task started (see it's wrapped in `using`). When you will invoke `CloseView()` you will call it on an already disposed object. Is it just a factory? Call it `*Factory` instead of `*Controller`. Is it a controller? Don't dispose it immediately but when you close the view (and check why your `Dispose()` method does nothing).</del>
- Why `RunTask()` instead of `StartNew()` or - better - `Run()` as `Task` and `TaskFactory` methods? I'd favor consistency with framework classes.
- Is there a specific reason you're using `Task.Factory.StartNew()` instead of `Task.Run()`? EDIT: OK, you're with .NET 4.0.
- `_AsyncTaskManager` (which BTW shouldn't be prefixed, it's *optional* for private fields and to avoid for types) is superfluous. It's just one method, it has no state and it's not persisted or passed around. You don't need a class but a *simple* private method.
- `Task` has a fluid interface, you can concatenate method calls `return Task.Run(...).ContinueWith(...).ContinueWith(...)`.
- In `CloseView()` you wait for dispatched action to terminate but you don't actually need to wait for UI to push thread back to the pool, in WinForms you may simply use `BeginInvoke()` because it doesn't need `EndInvoke()` to be called.

Ideally you wouldn't even need continuation tasks:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
    try
    {
        return taskFunc();
    }
    finally
    {
        feedBackView.CloseView();
    }
});
```

About exception management: you're doing *right*, if it's the way you want to handle errors. You close your view but `AggregateException` goes unnoticed. Here you may want to log such errors or to propagate them to UI thread (for example) again using `BeginInvoke`. See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997415(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! On the `Dispose` issue, you are missing that I'm calling `ShowDialog` juts after starting the task. The whole point is to have a responsive window that closes automatically *only* when the task has ended. I'm never closing  a disposed view.

Comment: Concerning why I'm not using `Task.Run()`, its simply because I am using .NET 4.0. `Run()` is available in .NET 4.5

Comment: Ok for Run() but you do not Dispose the view, you dispose the controller. The same instance you invoke for CliseView(). Parameters name are little bit incoherent (IMO) then it may go unnoticed.

Comment: Sorry, I've double checked and it's still the same reasoning. `ShowViewDialog()` is a blocking call, so it doesn't matter, the controller wont be disposed until the view is closed. The code can't exit the using block. `Dispose` implementation in the controller correctly disposes the view, so this is not an issue.

Comment: No, they are in different tasks! When the one calling CloseView() will be executed (continue with...) the one with ShowViewDialog() already completed and exited. Now, even assuming CloseView() does nothing at all then you are still calling Dispose() twice on your view. Objects must be resilient to this but calling code is still wrong (and it will fail when you will perform anything else, for example reading result from a control).  Moreover if sbowViewDialog() is modal (I don't know) you may not even need  then you may not need to explicitly close it.

Comment: Adriano, ShowViewDialog() is a **blocking** call. Execution will not advance past the call until the `View` is closed. There is no issue. Its the same as `Form.ShowDialog()`, the execution will halt until the `Form` is closed. What you are describing is the behavior of `Form.Show()`.

Comment: You dispose your CONTROLLER twice. In that blocking call and in continuation task!

Comment: Just run the code using a simple `Form` and `Form.ShowDialog` and you will see.

Comment: No no no, you are right! My bad, ShowDialog() is in caller thread, **if it's synchronous** with UI thread then it's blocking and controller will be disposed after form has been closed.

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**
Here is a little bit of cleanup. Now you can get back reference to `Task<T>`  before blocking starts: `TaskWithFeedback.Run()` is a non blocking call. It also works with `Form.Show()` and `Form.ShowModel()` in the view.

```
class TaskWithFeedback<TViewController> 
    where TViewController : IViewController, new()
{
    public static async Task<T> Run<T>(Func<T> function)
    {
        var context = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
        var view = new TViewController();
        var opening = new Task(view.ShowViewDialog);
        opening.Start(context);
        var task = Task.Run(function);
        var closing = task
            .ContinueWith(t => view.CloseViewDialog(), context);                

        try
        {                             
            return await task;
        }
        finally
        {
            await opening;
            await closing;
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Text = await TaskWithFeedback<Form2>.Run(() =>
            {
                Thread.Sleep(3000);
                return "Hello!";
            });            
    }   
}

class Form2 : Form, IViewController
{
    public void ShowViewDialog() => ShowDialog();
    public void CloseViewDialog() => Close();
}
```

Comment: That looks really nice but I cant use `async` / `await`. Currently stuck with .NET 4.0

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with C# or `Windows.Forms` for that matter. But I'll try to help you in regards to:

> Another issue I am not sure about is where is the best place to handle ArregateException?

Looking at the msdn docs you can deal with the task result in two ways:

- inside the `ContinueWith(...)` closure by specifying the correct `TaskContinuationOptions` (in your case, for dealing with any exceptions thrown, would be the `OnlyOnFaulted` enum option;
- try to access the `Result` property of the `Task` instance that you return. If the operation was unsuccessful, this will throw the underlying exception, which you can then handle.

Accessing the `Result` property later would make sense if you waited for the task to finish. But I guess that's not your use case (and the main reason you decided to do this in a `Task`). So I would just go with the `ContinueWith(...)`.

One final thing to bear in mind, (and I gladly welcome any C# developer to correct me on this one) is that a task is just a unit of work. A *process* if you want to think of it that way.

You give an operation to it (in this case the `Func`) and it will run it whenever it can. The `ContinueWith()` methods are just *continuations*, things that will run **after** the task is finished (being it an error, success, or cancel).

The responsibility of your `TaskManagerWithFeedbackDialog` is to run whatever operation you give it and deal with the success or failure of that operation. I hope this helps refactoring your original code.

Remember, keep it simple!